# Clean RHEL5 build from kickstart adds Public IP to /etc/hosts

Tags: installation, rhel5, hosts-file

Our infrastructure has a Kickstart server which can serve up RHEL6 builds with some post-installation scripting that handles customization and configuration. I'm currently in the process of updating the scripting to handle RHEL5 for those few instances that require it.

At this time, I have disabled the automatic execution of the scripts on a RHEL5 test build so that I can run them manually and evaluate output and errors.

I'm seeing an odd thing that I've never encountered before. On this clean build, the /etc/hosts file has an entry for a public IP (presumably one of our service provider's). I have no idea how it is getting added. NetworkManager isn't configured to run and I don't think it even has the ability to do that. I'm also pretty sure this is not default behavior for any version of RHEL.

Has anyone seen this before or have suggestions as to what I should be looking at to prevent it?

```
#version=RHEL5.7
text
install
reboot
url --url http://10.153.166.3/inst/dist/rhel5-7
lang en_US.UTF-8
keyboard us
network --device eth0 --bootproto static --ip 10.153.139.105 --netmask 255.255.255.240 --gateway 10.153.139.97 --hostname=tcecapm1r5ls02.ecap.cciio
network --device eth1 --bootproto static --ip 10.153.172.62 --netmask 255.255.255.192
rootpw --iscrypted $1$Qr2vVb30$k8ggH.4XAhIfTWhjo3Ju6.
key --skip
firewall --port=22
authconfig --enableshadow --passalgo=sha512
selinux --disabled
timezone --utc America/New_York
bootloader --location=mbr --driveorder=sda,sdb --append="crashkernel=auto"
# The following is the partition information you requested
# Note that any partitions you deleted are not expressed
# here so unless you clear all partitions first, this is
# not guaranteed to work
zerombr
clearpart --all --initlabel --drives=sda

part /boot --fstype=ext3 --size=200 --ondisk=sda
part pv.01 --size=200 --grow --ondisk=sda
volgroup VolGroup00 pv.01
logvol swap --fstype=swap --size=512 --vgname=VolGroup00 --name=logvol-swap
logvol / --fstype=ext3 --size=200 --grow --vgname=VolGroup00 --name=logvol-root

%packages
@base
@core
expect
telnet
net-snmp
pax
python-dmidecode
sgpio
arpwatch
nmap
iptraf
dropwatch
arptables_jf
nfs-utils
-autofs
-SDL
-theora-tools
-libtiff
-cups-libs
-libxcb
-libfontenc
-wireless-tools
-openjpeg-libs
-pcmciautils
-iw
-libhugetlbfs-utils
-alsa-utils
-fontpackages-filesystem
-pixman
-libjpeg
-libthai
-make
-cdparanoia-libs
-qt-sqlite
-valgrind
-oprofile
-setserial
-bridge-utils
-redhat-indexhtml
-aic94xx-firmware
-b43-openfwwf
-b43-fwcutter
-bfa-firmware
-ipw2100-firmware
-ipw2200-firmware
-ivtv-firmware
-iwl100-firmware
-iwl1000-firmware
-iwl3945-firmware
-iwl4965-firmware
-iwl5000-firmware
-iwl5150-firmware
-iwl6000-firmware
-iwl6000g2b-firmware
-iwl6000g2a-firmware
-iwl6050-firmware
-libertas-usb8388-firmware
-netxen-firmware
-ql2100-firmware
-ql2200-firmware
-ql2400-firmware
-ql2500-firmware
-ql23xx-firmware
-rt61pci-firmware
-rt73usb-firmware
-xorg-x11-drv-ati-firmware
-zd1211-firmware
-mesa-dri-drivers
-hicolor-icon-theme
-libpng
-libogg
-libtheora
-libvorbis
-libvisual
-atk
-smartmontools
-ypbind
-ipa-client
-oddjob-mkhomedir
-freetype
-kexec-tools
-openswan
-qt
-cups
-portreserve
-xmlrpc-c
-samba-common
-samba-client
-samba-winbind-clients
-cifs-utils
-dejavu-fonts-common
-dejavu-sans-fonts
-python-matplotlib
-words
-atmel-firmware
-cairo
-fontconfig
-fprintd
-fprintd-pam
-ghostscript
-ghostscript-fonts
-gstreamer
-gtk2
-hwloc
-latencytop
-libXfont
-libXft
-libfprint
-pango
-phonon-backend-gstreamer
-pycairo
-qt
-qt3
-redhat-lsb-graphics
-urw-fonts
-xorg-x11-font-utils
-dosfstools
-seekwatcher
-poppler
-poppler-data
-foomatic
-foomatic-db
-foomatic-db-ppds
-redhat-lsb
-redhat-lsp-printing

%post
sed -i 's/ rhgb quiet//' /boot/grub/grub.conf
mkdir /usr/local/src/scripts
mkdir /usr/local/src/files
cd /usr/local/src/scripts
wget http://10.153.166.3/inst/post-install-dev/post-install-scripts.tar.gz
tar zxvf /usr/local/src/scripts/post-install-scripts.tar.gz
cd /usr/local/src/files
wget http://10.153.166.3/inst/post-install-dev/post-install-files.tar.gz
tar zxvf /usr/local/src/files/post-install-files.tar.gz
/usr/local/src/scripts/post-conf
```

EDIT: Added kickstart file.

Comment: Add your ks.cfg file to the question.

Comment: And it's not the hostname and ip-address that was assigned for the kickstart?

Comment: It is the hostname, but not the IP. I don't know even know where the IP would be coming from. It isn't one that we use. I've added the kickstart file to the body of the question.